# I can't add an item to my cart, why? Trying to get property 'products' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to get property 'products' of non-object

```
if ($order->products->contains($productId))
```

code snippet
BasketController.php

```
public function basketAdd($productId)
    {
        $orderId = session('orderId');
        if (is_null($orderId)) {
            $order = Order::create();
            session(['orderId' => $order->id]);
        } else {
            $order = Order::find($orderId);
        }
        **if ($order->products->contains($productId)) **
        {
            $pivotRow = $order->products()->where('product_id', $productId)->first()->pivot;
            $pivotRow->count++;
            $pivotRow->update();

        } else
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `Order::find(...)` can return `null`

Answer (score 1):

First remove ** before and after if, after try:

```
$productions = $order->with(['products' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', $productId);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).